# Right sidebar on Twitter Bootstrap 2

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, css-float, sidebar

I've seen a few guides (including one or two stackoverflow questions), but pretty much all say that this is a fix for 1.4 that is built into 2.*.

Working from the [fluid example](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/examples/fluid.html) I tried adding the `pull-right` attribute to various levels of the `div`s with no success.

**How do I get a right-sidebar with [Twitter Bootstrap 2](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/)?**

Comment: can you show us what you tried? what is not working as expected?

Comment: I have tried adding the `pull-right` attribute to the div classes: `"container-fluid"`, `"row-fluid"`, `"span3"`, `"well sidebar-nav"` and `"nav nav-list"`, however instead of moving to the right of the screen the best it has done is move it to the right of the left sidebar.

Comment: Could you please show html code or fiddle

Comment: Are you looking for the sidebar to be at the top when the responsive stylesheet kicks in (while being positioned on the right side)? I answered a question much like this one before and the same approach can be formatted for this question.

Comment: Hmm, actually for this use-case the right sidebar being below and the left sidebar being on top would be best. Show your solution though, as it'll probably go a long way to answering my question :)

Comment: @AT i'm confused, right and left sidebar? You mean on a three column setup? [Like this one](http://jsfiddle.net/andresilich/6vPqA/13/show/), or just a basic two-column setup with the sidebar to the right, [like this one](http://jsfiddle.net/6de6S/show/)?

Comment: [This one](http://jsfiddle.net/andresilich/6vPqA/13/show/), but with the page content (Hello world and whatnot) shrinking to in-between the right and left sidebar for mobiles.

Comment: @AT mm, i'm still unsure, like this? http://jsfiddle.net/6vPqA/89/ .. by the way, you can page somebody by typing `@` plus their username in the first line of the comments box, that way they'll receive a message.

Comment: That last fiddle was perfect, thanks @AndresIlich. Can you post the as an answer so I can accept it? :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get a fluid three-column bootstrap setup by simply laying out three divs that equal the highest possible grid setup there is, which is `.span12`. So in this case we used three divs, 2x sidebar `.span3` divs + 1x `.span6` content div and all equals 12.

**HTML**

```
<div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="navbar-inner">

    <div class="container-fluid">
      <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </a>
      <a class="brand" href="#">Project name</a>
      <div class="btn-group pull-right">

        <a class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
          <i class="icon-user"></i> Username
          <span class="caret"></span>
        </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
          <li class="divider"></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sign Out</a></li>

        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="nav-collapse">
        <ul class="nav">
          <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>

        </ul>
      </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span3">

      <div class="well sidebar-nav">
        <ul class="nav nav-list">
          <li class="nav-header">Sidebar</li>
          <li class="active"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>

          <li class="nav-header">Sidebar</li>
          <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>

          <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
          <li class="nav-header">Sidebar</li>
          <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        </ul>

      </div><!--/.well -->
    </div><!--/span-->
    <div class="span6">
      <div class="hero-unit">
        <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
        <p>This is a template for a simple marketing or informational website. It includes a large callout called the hero unit and three supporting pieces of content. Use it as a starting point to create something more unique.</p>
        <p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-large">Learn more &raquo;</a></p>

      </div>
      <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span4">
          <h2>Heading</h2>
          <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
          <p><a class="btn" href="#">View details &raquo;</a></p>
        </div><!--/span-->

        <div class="span4">
          <h2>Heading</h2>
          <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
          <p><a class="btn" href="#">View details &raquo;</a></p>
        </div><!--/span-->
        <div class="span4">
          <h2>Heading</h2>

          <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
          <p><a class="btn" href="#">View details &raquo;</a></p>
        </div><!--/span-->
      </div><!--/row-->
      <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span4">
          <h2>Heading</h2>

          <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
          <p><a class="btn" href="#">View details &raquo;</a></p>
        </div><!--/span-->
        <div class="span4">
          <h2>Heading</h2>
          <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
          <p><a class="btn" href="#">View details &raquo;</a></p>

        </div><!--/span-->
        <div class="span4">
          <h2>Heading</h2>
          <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
          <p><a class="btn" href="#">View details &raquo;</a></p>
        </div><!--/span-->
      </div><!--/row-->

    </div><!--/span-->
    <div class="span3">

      <div class="well sidebar-nav">
        <ul class="nav nav-list">
          <li class="nav-header">Sidebar</li>
          <li class="active"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>

          <li class="nav-header">Sidebar</li>
          <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>

          <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
          <li class="nav-header">Sidebar</li>
          <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        </ul>

      </div><!--/.well -->
    </div><!--/span-->
  </div><!--/row-->

  <hr>

  <footer>
    <p>&copy; Company 2012</p>
  </footer>

</div><!--/.fluid-container-->
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/6vPqA/89/